# Is it always possible to draw an Euler diagram with $2^n$ distinct regions?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, plane-curves, combinatorial-geometry

Assume we have a set $L$ of $n$ Jordan curves which intersect each other and divide a plane into regions. Given a region $r$, we characterize it by $C(r)=\{l \in L: \text{$r$ lies inside $l$}\}$. Let us say that regions $r$ and $s$ are equal if they have the same characteristics, i.e. $C(r)=C(s)$. Is it always possible to draw the curves and get $2^n$ regions without equal regions?

The folowing picture demonstrates all the main possibilities for $n=3$ (the third case satisfies our conditions): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbN4M.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for [Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) (that are Euler diagrams in which all combination of intersections are present).
[Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets) the following sequence with this property:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And another one, called *Edwards–Venn diagrams*:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And finally, an idea of my own that is easily described with explicit formulas: you could choose the regions under the curves

$$2^{-n}\sin(2^n x), \quad x\in[0,2\pi],$$

appropriately cropped to give you finite regions that are bounded by Jordan curves.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Interesting. The last representation '"idea of your own", is very alike the first one of the previous line, but more "practical" is one can say such a thing...

Comment: Take a look at the astonishing PhD thesis about "Generation  and drawing of area-proportional
Euler and Venn Diagrams" https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf40/da80ff2cb3db9f642bf8bb898027e258eca7.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie This is indeed astonishing! Thank you for that link. And yes, "my idea" was probably inspired by the second example ;).